# Drop duplicates from a panda dataframe based on other column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe which I am using is as below:

```
Name    NoOfTrans   Avg_pass_time    Cons.Error            RunCounts
Jan     0                            Failed:abcd           4
Jan                                                        4
Jan                                                        4
Jan                                                        4
May     2                            Failed:abcFailed:cde  5
May                                                        5
May                  1200                                  5
May                  1200                                  5
May                                                        5
```

I need to remove the duplicate from "Name", "Avg_pass_time" and "RunCounts" columns group by the "Name" column so that the output is as below:

```
Name    NoOfTrans   Avg_pass_time    Cons.Error            RunCounts
Jan     0                            Failed:abcd           4
May     2           1200             Failed:abcFailed:cde  5
```

Any guide will be usefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If per groups are only empty strings or duplicated values use:

```
df = df.replace('',np.nan).groupby('Name', as_index=False).first().fillna('')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select a subset of rows that will be used to drop the duplicates:

```py
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name','Avg_pass_time','RunCounts'])
```

Untested but this should work.

Comment: this is fine but its still keeping blank rows for Avg_pass_time field